# Nginx proxy, to hit multiple host based on the path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

The requirement is to hit the endpoint based on the request path, for example, if its /bsc the request should go to these two, and similarly for other path as well, following is what I have which is working

```
upstream bsc_backend {
    least_conn;
    server bsc-mainnet.gateway.network:443;
    server nd-744-07-279.com:443 backup;
}

upstream eth_backend {
    least_conn;
    server nd-860-422-720.com:443;
    server eth-mainnet.gateway.network:443 backup;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /proxy/bsc {
        proxy_set_header Host bsc-mainnet.gateway.network:443;
        proxy_pass https://bsc_backend/v1/lb/62cffbe1b37b8e00392b3872;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

    location /proxy/eth {
        proxy_set_header Host nd-860-422-720.com:443;
        proxy_pass https://eth_backend/df11e01c3738cc840cc407a78131d596;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }
}
```

Tow issues with hardcoding here, one is the proxy_set_header, I have tried all the internal variable like $host, $upstream_addr $upstream__host_addr, some of these are empty and some are returning IP address instead of domain name

Secon issue is the remove the hardcoding in path which changes based on currently active upstream.

Please through some inputs on this, I am struggling. Also please let me know if I should use something else instead of nginx.

Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying